# java coding standard for garbage memory support

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, memory-management

```
simpleClass sc =  new simpleClass();
sc.getObject();
...
```

simpleClass.java

```
    class simpleClass {

    static int st = 0;

    public Integer getObject() {
        Integer i = 10;
        Integer j = 10;
        Integer result = 10;

        try {
            result = getSum(i, j);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            i = null;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Integer getSum(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Please explain which variable/Object are **eligible for Garbage and when**?

which stay in memory until what time?

what to do for object that is eligible for Garbage memory but still in memory?

Untill when in memory,  is the life and impression.

my friends and i already debated for this and still going on with so many different Statements.

Answer (score 1):

Why not read up on some things about Java garbage collection instead of arguing :)? For instance http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11253/ or http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html .

There are definitions there for the so called **root set**, which essentially consists of static references (which you have none of in your code, as `static int` is not a reference) or stack variables which are locals (`Integer i`/ `Integer j`/ `Integer result`) as well as parameters (Integer a/ Integer b) during execution of a method. So during the execution of `getObject()`, the objects referenced by i, j ans result will be part of the root set and not eligible for gc (as well as any objects that might be indirectly referenced by those). Once once `getObject()` finishes however, i's and j's objects can be removed. The result object will stay in the root set, if its assigned to another local variable, i.e. if you do something like `Object o = aSimpleClass.getObject()`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see.

```
class simpleClass {
   static int st = 0;
```

The `st` variable is not used at all - is this intentional?

```
   public Integer getObject(){
          Interger i = 10;
          Interger j = 10;
          Interger result = 10;
```

I suppose these should be `Integer`. So, here you are creating 3 variables, and assign them all the same object, namely the result from `Integer.valueOf(10)`. This method is guaranteed to return the same object for the same input, at least for small values. It usually stores these values in a static array in the Integer class, I think.

```
          try{    
              result = getSum(i, j);
```

Here you invoke the `getSum` method - this (if corrected) returns another object, which is the same as `Integer.valueOf(20)`.

```
          }catch(Exception ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
```

If there was an exception (it is not, if you don't override the sum method in a subclass), you would here catch and print the exception object, and then throw it away.

So, one object (and its contained stacktrace objects) available for garbage collection.

```
          } finally{
              i = null;
```

Here you are assigning `null` to the `i` variable. If `i` contained an object which was only referenced through `i`, it would now be available for garbage collection, but since it is also in the `j` variable (and supposedly also somewhere in a static variable in `Integer`), it isn't.

```
          }
          return result;
```

We end the method - so now all its local variables (`i`, `j` , `result`) are ended. The `20` object (in `result`) is returned, thus now the responsibility of the calling method. The `10` object (in `j`) is not anymore referenced from this thread (at least not in the code we see), so it could be freed - but as said, usually the `Integer` class keeps a reference to this object, so no garbage collection here.

```
   }
   public Interger getSum(Interger a, Interger b){
         retrun a  + b;
   }
```

Please, when posting code, at least run it through a compiler before. It's `Integer` and `return`.

```
}
```

Comment: thanx buddy but after completing/execution method's object are eligible for Garbage collection itSelf so no need to do i = null; and j = null;

Comment: There is no need for `i=null` and `j = null` in this simple method, no. For very long-running methods it may make sense, but only think about such optimizations if you have memory or performance problems, and then measure it.